# search a var in script tag by bs4 & python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-re

```
url = "www.xxxx.com"
rlink = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies).content
html = BeautifulSoup(rlink, 'html.parser')
scripttags = html.findAll("script")
```

In html DOM, it will have about 7x script tags, I need to search a variable (unique) in
every script tag

variable is

```
var playbackUrl = 'https://www.yyyy.com'
```

```
for i in range(len(scripttags)):
    if "playbackUrl" in str(scripttags[i]):
        for j in str(scripttags[i]).split("\n"):
            if "playbackUrl" in j:
                url_=re.search("'(.*)'", j).group(1)
                print(url_)
```

though my script can do the job, however, just wonder if any smart way to do the task

Comment: Post the url you are trying to scrape

Comment: nah, its a video purchase site, just thinking a way to be done by one search/loop

Comment: there is no method to search directly in scripts - so you have to use `for`-loop to check every script separatellly.

Comment: code could be more readable if you learn to use `for`-loop without `range(len())` and later `[i]` - `for script in scripttags:`

Comment: you don't have to split into line but use `re.findall("var playbackUrl = '(.*)'", script.text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code can be more readable if you learn to use `for`-loop without `range(len())`

And you don't have to split it into lines

```
html = '''<script>
var other = 'test';
var playbackUrl = 'https://www.example1.com';
var next = 'test';
</script>

<script>
var other = 'test';
var playbackUrl = 'https://www.example2.com';
var next = 'test';
</script>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
scripttags = soup.find_all("script")

for script in scripttags:
    
    results = re.search("var playbackUrl = '(.*)'", script.text)
    if results:
        print('search:', results[1])
    
    # OR
    
    results = re.findall("var playbackUrl = '(.*)'", script.text)
    if results:
        print('findall:', results[0])
```

Result:

```
search: https://www.example1.com
findall: https://www.example1.com

search: https://www.example2.com
findall: https://www.example2.com
```

Comment: hmm, i have no idea I need to add a if condition, `for script in scripttags: if "playbackUrl" in script.text: print('findall:', re.findall("var playbackUrl = '(.*)'", script.text)[0])`
otherwise it will return nth, and error in IndexError: list index out of range
but anyway it simplifies my scripts a lot

Comment: you could get `findall()` without `[0]` and later check `if results:  print(results[0])`. I added this to code in question.